# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytest'

Tags: python, pytest

After installing the `pytest` module in a virtual environment, I used the python code to call and run the prompt to find the `pytest` module.

I installed the pytest module outside the virtual environment. I can call it normally with python.

```
import pytest


def test_main():
    assert 5!=5

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main()
```

The error is as follows：

> [Running] python -u "d:\MyPytest\test_sample.py"
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "d:\MyPytest\test_sample.py", line 1, in 
>           import pytest
>       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytest'
>       [Done] exited with code=1 in 0.185 seconds

Comment: Bumped into the same problem. In my case the problem was that I installed pytest with pip3.9, whereas I built the virtual environment with Python 3.8 and used pip3.8 to install previous packages. So maybe you used different Python versions or pip versions in your virtual environment

Answer (score 44):

**TLDR:** I suspect you installed `pytest` within your system level `python` site-packages so when you try to run `pytest`, within your `virtualenv`, it's throwing a `ModuleNotFoundError` since it doesn't have this dependency installed within your `virtualenv`. Virtual environments give you a sandboxed environment so you can experiment with potential `python` libraries for your project, but they're self contained and don't have access to your system level python third-party libraries.

Typically an `ImportError` is raised when an *import statement has trouble successfully importing the specified module*. If the problem is due to an *invalid or incorrect path*, this will raise a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

From your question it *isn't clear where you installed `pytest`* since you said you installed it within your `virtualenv` then you said you installed it outside your `virtualenv` on your System level `python` site-packages.. So I will give my thoughts for getting `pytest` to work within a `virtualenv`, since this is probably what you want:

Virtualenv are nice because they give you a **sandboxed environment to play around with python libraries,** safe from messing up your system level `python` configurations. Now the `ModuleNotFoundError` is thrown within your `virtualenv` because it **can't find the `pytest` module for the test you're trying to run.** Maybe you could try *activating your `virtualenv` and re-installing `pytest` within this `virtualenv`* and seeing if this course of action resolves your issue:

**Activate your virtualenv:**

```
# Posix systems
source /path/to/ENV/bin/activate

# Windows
\path\to\env\Scripts\activate
```

**Install `pytest` within your virtualenv:**

**Note**: you should see your `virtualenv's` name listed in parenthesizes before installing `pytest`. For this example, suppose you created a virtual environment named: `env`

```
(env) pip install pytest
```

Now `pytest` will be available to you within your `virtualenv`. For more information checkout `virtualenv`'s [documentation](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/#usage). I would also suggest looking into [virtualenvwrapper,](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which nicely wraps around `virtualenv` for more convenient commands to activate/deactivate `virtualenvs`.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Hello, I can activate the virtual environment on the command line, but I can't find the module when I run the code runner plugin in vscode. In the vscode, I also activate the virtual environment.

Comment: So you need to make sure you see pytest within your virtualenv, usually this is located: in your home directory and .virtualenvs folder:  ~/.virtualenvs/<env>/lib/<python_ver>/site-packages if you see it in there then you don't have to install it, if you don't install it in that virtualenv. Then within your visual studio code ide you need to specify to use this virtualenv. Checkout https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments then you should be able to run your project with the code runner

Comment: @御弟哥哥 did my answer help you out?

Answer (score 13):

If it's not the virtualenv case, then try `python3 -m pytest`.

Answer (score 2):

The Python error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytest'" occurs for multiple reasons:

1. Not having the pytest package installed by running pip install
   pytest.
2. Installing the package in a different Python version than the one
   you're using.
3. Installing the package globally and not in your virtual environment.
4. Your IDE running an incorrect version of Python.

See the details [here](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-no-module-named-pytest).

Answer (score 0):

In my case if I use vscode terminal. I get same error.
Then I tried same using CMD and its working.
So I suggest to use system terminal instead of any third party terminal.

`cmd: python -m pytest`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I actually had it installed.
Restarting my terminal and re-entering the virtual environment worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was solved like described in [this article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/9007972337682-No-module-named-pytest-within-PyCharm-works-in-Python-CLI) from the JetBrains community:

> - WORKAROUND *
>
> Go to 'Settings -> Tools -> Python Integrated Tools' and scroll down
> to where it says `pytest not found` and there is a `FIX` button.