# Python3 import Error: No module named 'pytest'

Tags: python-3.x, import

I have installed pytest successfully,but import error occurs "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytest'".I can see pytest in my finder but it not in the "python3 -m pip list".How can I solve it?

```
HelendeMacBook-Pro:bin helendai$ pip3 install pytest
Collecting pytest
  Using cached pytest-5.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (246 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: more-itertools>=4.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pytest) (8.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pytest) (20.3)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pytest) (19.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pluggy<1.0,>=0.12 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pytest) (0.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: py>=1.5.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pytest) (1.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pytest) (0.1.9)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata>=0.12; python_version < "3.8" in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pytest) (1.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from packaging->pytest) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from packaging->pytest) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from importlib-metadata>=0.12; python_version < "3.8"->pytest) (3.1.0)
Installing collected packages: pytest
Successfully installed pytest-5.4.1
HelendeMacBook-Pro:bin helendai$ python3 -m pip list
Package      Version   
------------ ----------
certifi      2019.11.28
cffi         1.14.0    
chardet      3.0.4     
cryptography 2.8       
idna         2.9       
pip          20.0.2    
pycparser    2.20      
pyOpenSSL    19.1.0    
PyYAML       5.3       
requests     2.23.0    
setuptools   41.2.0    
six          1.14.0    
urllib3      1.25.8    
HelendeMacBook-Pro:bin helendai$ python3
Python 3.8.2 (v3.8.2:7b3ab5921f, Feb 24 2020, 17:52:18) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pytest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytest'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h2DD.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytest'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55652866/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pytest)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you had installed multiple python on your computer, because the install logs show pytest is installed on python 3.6, but the python shell show your python version is 3.8.2