# VSCode cannot detect pytest unit tests, behind company's proxy

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

[Error discovering pytest tests,see Output -> Python screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4lhC.png)

One strange thing I notice in the above screenshot is: it always has a "d" inside the search bar under Testing even I closed and re-open VSCode, you can see it from the screenshot above.

[I checked pytest has been installed, screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVTqs.png)

Here is the output content from Output -> Python.
The "import pytest" error comes from the .vscode-server folder.

I am using VSCode 1.69.2, Windows 10 OS

> LSP Notebooks experiment is disabled -- not in treatment group
>
> > python -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> > python -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)" Python interpreter path: /usr/local/bin/python
> > python -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)" Starting Pylance language server.
> > python -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> > python -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> > python -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> > python -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> > python ./.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.10.1/pythonFiles/testing_tools/run_adapter.py
> > discover pytest -- --rootdir . -s --cache-clear workflow cwd: . [ERROR
> > 2022-6-26 13:1:2.338]: Error discovering pytest tests:  [n [Error]:
> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> > "/home/cdsw/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.10.1/pythonFiles/testing_tools/run_adapter.py",
> > line 17, in 
> > from testing_tools.adapter.**main** import parse_args, main   File "/home/cdsw/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.10.1/pythonFiles/testing_tools/adapter/**main**.py",
> > line 9, in 
> > from . import pytest, report   File "/home/cdsw/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.10.1/pythonFiles/testing_tools/adapter/pytest/**init**.py",
> > line 7, in 
> > from ._discovery import discover   File "/home/cdsw/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.10.1/pythonFiles/testing_tools/adapter/pytest/_discovery.py",
> > line 8, in 
> > import pytest ImportError: No module named pytest
>
> at ChildProcess.
> (/home/cdsw/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.10.1/out/client/extension.js:2:232783)
> at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26)  at ChildProcess.emit
> (node:events:390:28)  at maybeClose
> (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)     at
> Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
> (node:internal/child_process:301:5)]
>
> > python -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"

So as you can see that I have installed the pytest, but the .vscode-server still complains about it.

Comment: Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55652866/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pytest) help? Try to activate your virtualenv and reinstall pytest.

Comment: thanks @MingJie-MSFT I found the issue. I will write the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to bring up the command palate and type:
"Python: Select Interpreter" to select a running Python interpreter.

By default, the VSCode picked up a corrupted conda environment on my PC which caused this issue. I have created a PR for them and it has been assigned to sb.

Also there is another cause for this problem, in my case, our company has Python 3.6 which is not supported in the latest Python Extension for VSCode. Once I downgraded the Python Extension to older version which supports Python 3.6, the Unit Tests can be found again.